# How to decide when to give the header, footer correct the route in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, authentication, angular-ui-router, dashboard, angular7

could you help me with the following situation:

I need to go from a login to the dashboard using the app.routes, but the dashboard uses other tags like the app-header, when the login does not, for example in app.component.html this would be what I have for handling routing:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-left-menu></app-left-menu>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <app-footer></app-footer>
    <app-right-menu></app-right-menu>
</div>
```

but the login only needs the `<router-outlet> </ router-outlet>` without the other tags, how can I do that interaction, I have in mind a ngIf where I put the div to the wrapper and another to the `<router-outlet > </ router-outlet>` directly for the login. Would this be a good idea? How to change the variable of the ngIf when navigating to another screen? Is there any more specific way to go from a login to a dashboard protecting all the routes of the dashboard to redirect to the login? I would appreciate the help.

Comment: you mean when you login you want to hide header and footer?

Comment: Yes, with the `<div class="wrapper"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do that is with Feature Modules, if you have separated functionality you can create a specific module for each one. That's give to you more flexity, clean code and separate of concerns also obtain better perfomance because you can lazy load the modules. Check the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules.

For example you can define a module as entry point for your application when the user is loged, called InsideModule, this module have your own routing, called InsideRoutingModule and it could look like this:

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: InsideComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
      },

    ]
}
```

So the InsideComponent is the html to render inside this module and here you can use the common tags cross to application:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-left-menu></app-left-menu>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <app-footer></app-footer>
    <app-right-menu></app-right-menu>
</div>
```

To access to this module, import them in the app.module and modify the app.routing as follow:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'inside',
        loadChildren: () => InsideModule //this is lazy loading
    }
];
```

Or simply redirect to the path you have in the InsideRoutingModule via router.

The app.module.html only have a `<router-outlet>` tag

Comment: I put this routes ` [ {path: 'access', component: AccessComponent, children: [
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: 'recovery', component: RecoveryComponent }
    ]},
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
        { path: 'blank', component: BlankComponent}
    ]},
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'access/login'},
    { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'access/login'}` But when i put 'access' without child route,  this show me a empty page with te access style. How to prevent access to parent?

Comment: You can set the path { path: ' ', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'} as children in your 'access' path, so when you navigate to /access, the router redirect to '/access/login